# In gitlab/git, any way to switch which repo is the "source of truth"?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

So, playing around with a little project on my own time, it became something more.  Now we'd like to have a Gitlab repo that's the "Source Of Truth" that we then can deploy with Jenkins, eventually to our production environment.  We'd prefer that repo not be my personal one.

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how, either from the command line or within my Gitlab web console, to create a new repo to be The Repo from which all other forks will derive.  I tried simply forking in Gitlab but if I make changes to my "personal" fork, I can't use the "Merge Request" option to push them to the new "Upstream" repo; merges only work in the other direction.

I guess I can try to delete my personal repo and then fork anew from the "upstream" one, but that makes me nervous.  Is there no built-in way to tell gitlab that a certain repo is now the upstream-est of them all?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is why SCMs have branching facility. Read a bit in detail on [git-scm website](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is).

For your case, you can have a branch `production` which is what will be deployed, and the other contributors can keep developing into their own branches. The merge requests (or patches) will be applied to production branch after reviews etc.

Comment: In the end, I just deleted my personal repo and reforked it from the new "master".  That seems to work fine.

The branching technique probably works better, but it's not the way we do things at the office, so I'm not sufficiently familiar with it.  I'll play around with it, though.

Answer (score 0):

If we ignore the cloud source code repository systems (Gitlab, Github, etc.) for a moment - all git repos are peers. One given repo being a "central" repo is really a matter of you and your team deciding it is.

All you need to do is get everything from the forked repo into a local repo you have control of, then create a new empty "central" repo on Gitlab, and push up all branches, etc., to it from your local repo.

It sounds like this is essentially what you've already done.

---

## Further discussion of "central" repos, forks, etc.

Git does allows you to create a "bare" repository, which means it is intended to be a central repo of some sort, because it doesn't have a working directory.  This is what all the cloud repo systems use (the folder for bare repos is named `[repo].git` rather than having a separate `.git` folder inside the repo (i.e. `[repo]/.git`).  But other than that, as long as you fetch all branches and tags, and recursively pull all submodules, etc., then your local repo has all the same info that a remote repo has, and, in fact, your repo can then serve as a remote repo for another local repo somewhere else.

Now, in addition to this, Gitlab, Github, and similar services, do provide some additional means of access protection, where you can "protect" a branch so only certain people can merge in pull requests, for example, and the use of forks which give other team members or teams (or even just random people on the internet) the ability to create a personal copy of the repo.  But even then, if they wanted to make their fork into a separate repo, they can just clone everything down into their local repo, and then have other people connect to it, or push it to a new empty repo at Gitlab, etc.

Now, this all being said, you do generally need to run a few commands in special ways to make sure you are pulling down all history, all commits, all branches, all tags to make sure you really have everything, but after that's done, there is nothing special about a given repo.  That's part of the beauty of Git - if you have the repo, you have everything, so you can work completely offline, backup the entire repo just by copying the folder, etc.